# Where to find same implementation for "load_der_public_key" in java

Tags: java, python, cryptography

Python has a very good library for Cryptography

For example for "load_der_public_key" https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/

Code in python

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_public_key

der_public_key = base64.b64decode(public_key_b64)

public_key = load_der_public_key(der_public_key)
```

I know how to convert PEM to DER
https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

Use dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>

String decodedString = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(data));
```

What about load_der_public_key. Is there something similar in JAVA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it is an 8-liner. Usually the public key isa PEM encoded string looking like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S
...
QwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

For a RSA public key use this code (I used the Java built-in Base64 decoder):

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    String publicKeyPEM = key;
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "");
    byte[] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pubKey = (PublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
    return pubKey;
}
```

If you "just" have the Base64 encoded data part you can leave out the "stripping off" of the header and footer.

Comment: Thank you. It is actually ECDSA algorithm. I need to use KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")